# Thread variables keep changing

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads running via this same class BouncingObject.  A BouncingObject just keeps bouncing off the screen boundaries.  At certain points I want to redefine those screen boundaries in the main thread.  But for some reason it doesn't quite work.  When I alter the screen boundaries with the alterBounceBoundaries method it alters them, but not completely.  The boundary values keep varying between the set boundaries using the method and the initialized values.  Why?.  As you can see I print out the values of the limits as the thread runs and I can see that the values of orig_x,orig_y,lim_x,lim_y switch between the altered values and the initialized ones.  Those values are how the bounceobject detects the screen boundaries.

```
class BouncingObject extends D_Object implements Runnable 
{   
    public int MAX_SPEED = 20;
    public int MIN_SPEED = 10;
    public volatile double orig_x = 0;
    public volatile double orig_y = 0;
    public volatile double lim_x = 0;
    public volatile double lim_y = 0;
    public String rand = "rand";

    BouncingObject(String nm,BufferedImage image, int x,int y, int w, int h, int ox, int oy, int spd){
        super(nm,image,x,y,w,h,ox,oy,spd);
        orig_x = 0;
        orig_y = 0;
        lim_x = 603;
        lim_y = 393;
        Thread new_bounce_thread = new Thread(this); 
        new_bounce_thread.start();
    }

    //run this code in it's own thread
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            //sleep for a short time to create a slower frame rate
            try {Thread.sleep (20); }  
            catch (InterruptedException e){} 
            this.bounceObject(orig_x,orig_y,lim_x,lim_y,"rand");
            System.out.println("orig_x: "+orig_x);
            System.out.println("orig_y: "+orig_y);
            System.out.println("lim_x: "+lim_x);
            System.out.println("lim_y: "+lim_y);
        }
    }

public synchronized void alterBounceBoundaries(double origin_x, double origin_y, double limit_x, double limit_y, String rand_o_no){
        orig_x = origin_x;
        orig_y = origin_y;
        lim_x = limit_x;
        lim_y = limit_y;
        rand = rand_o_no;
        System.out.println("Change Boundaries");
    }

//used to determine when the bouncingobject has reached a little and needs to bounce
public synchronized void bounceObject(double origin_x, double origin_y, double limit_x, double limit_y, String rand_o_no){
        if(obj_x > old_obj_x){
            old_obj_x = obj_x;
....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two threads running bouncing objects you probably have two objects being bounced. I am willing to bet you are only changing the limits on one of them.

Essentially, when you want to change your limits, make sure you change the limits on all of the objects.

Another alternative would be to make the limits `static` so they are shared by all instances of the object.

Comment: That helped but I still have the issue that the object doesn't react to the x and y limits.  It doesn't bounce off them, it bounces off only the initialized x and y limits

Comment: I now know why it printed out both the initialized values and the new ones, because I have two BouncingObject threads, but I don't understand why when I run this the BouncingObject doesn't react when its boundaries are altered.

Comment: If you decide to make the limits `static` then all Bouncing objects will share the same limits. As yours are not `static`, each object will have its own copy of the limits. Change them to `static` and your confusion will disappear - but you will have to change your locking mechanism.